# PropertyChangeListener and polymorphism inconsistencies (with packages)

Tags: java, groovy, polymorphism, propertychangelistener

When the following classes are separated into different packages it null-pointers: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addPropertyChangeListener() on null object.` Combining them into a single package, however, works.

Package `parents`:

```
package parents

import groovy.beans.Bindable
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

@Bindable
class GrandParent<T extends Parent> implements PropertyChangeListener {
  String pets
  GrandParent() {
    this.addPropertyChangeListener(this)
  }
  @Override
  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    println "prop change -> $evt"
  }
}

class Parent extends GrandParent {}
```

Package `children`

```
package children

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import groovy.beans.Bindable
import parents.*

class Child extends Parent {
  @Bindable 
  String brothers
  static main(args) {
    Child child = new Child()
    child.pets = "Leo, Sophie"
    child.brothers = "Douglas, Ted"
  }
}
```

Put them all together into one package/file (commenting out `import parents.*`) and you'll find it works, printing:

```
> prop change -> java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent[propertyName=pets; oldValue=null; newValue=Leo, Sophie; propagationId=null; source=children.Child@7eceb95b]
> prop change -> java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent[propertyName=brothers; oldValue=null; newValue=Douglas, Ted; propagationId=null; source=children.Child@7eceb95b]
```

Why is that?

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you put the classes into corresponding sub-directories when specifying packages?

Comment: I have them as two eclipse projects: one for the parent and grandparent classes, and one for the child class (referencing the parents' project). Just to be sure, after your comment I verified that a colleague of mine saw this same problem as well (if they used two different projects).

Comment: Odd... @Steinar it turns out it didn't matter whether or not it was in the same project. I found it necessary to add `<Parent>` to the `Parent` class definition, like this:
    public class Parent extends GrandParent <Parent> {
With that change, no more null pointers...(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the generic `<Parent>` to the Parent class declaration got things running again:

```
public class Parent extends GrandParent <Parent> { ... }
```